# Display all prime number pairs whose sum is N

Tags: matlab, primes, goldbach-conjecture

I am working on a code for Goldbach Conjecture to display the prime number pairs whose sum is equal to a positive even number N. I was able to find these prime number pairs but I want to print all these prime number pairs equal to N in one single line.

Any clue on how I would be able to work it out to achieve the desired result? This is the code I have worked out:

```
function goldB(N)
    for x = 6:2:N
        P = primes(x);
        for y = 1:length(primes(x))
            for z = 0:(length(P)-y)
                if P(y) + P(y+z) == x
                    fprintf('\n%d = %d + %d',x,P(y),P(y+z));
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to change the function call so that it prints the target number separately (along with a newline), and then also prints all the pairs associated with it (as they are found):

```
function goldB(N)
    for x = 6:2:N
        fprintf('\n%d', x);
        P = primes(x);
        for y = 1:length(primes(x))
            for z = 0:(length(P)-y)               
                if P(y) + P(y+z) == x
                    fprintf('= %d + %d', P(y), P(y+z));
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```